# clickable labels or writable buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a multiple choice quiz application for iPhone. The text is displayed in a label, as are the different answer choices, however, I couldn't find a way to make labels clickable to let the application know which answer choice was selected. I then thought I might be able to use buttons for the answer choices by setting the button title to be each answer choice, however when I do that it says `assignment to read only property`

```
self.answerChoice1.titleLabel = answerChoice1;
```

Is there a way to make either of these alternatives (clickable labels, or writable buttons) work, if not how would I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use buttons but your attempt to set the label isn't valid.

Use:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Some Label" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Please see the docs for `UIButton`.

If you want to use tappable labels, you need to enable user interaction on the label and then apply a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label.